# haskell Chess Knight Tour: Function composition

Tags: haskell, chess, function-composition, knights-tour, dot-operator

I've a hard time understanding a Chess Knight problem concerning
function composition. The exercise is a generator/filter/selector 
chain with a given wrapper function (knightProblem) which glues everything together.

It is unclear to me how the function kGenerator as the first piece in the chain should handle multiple parameters:

```
-- Chess Knight Problem: Generate all Knight moves of length NrMoves
-- that end at the target position
knightProblem :: StartPos -> NrMoves -> TargetPos -> [Moves]
knightProblem =  kSelector . kFilter . kGenerator 

-- kGenerator: needs StartPos, NrMoves, generates all sequences of length NrMoves
-- kFilter: remove all moves which contain invalid positions
-- kSelector: keep all moves which terminate at TargetPos

kGenerator :: ???
???
```

I'm looking for hints on how to handle this kind of problems.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing down type signatures for the other functions.

```
-- kSelector: keep all moves which terminate at TargetPos
-- something like
kSelector :: Position -> [Moves] -> [Moves]

-- kFilter: remove all moves which contain invalid positions
-- something like
kFilter :: [Moves] -> [Moves]
```

So it looks like `kGenerator` should provide `kFilter` with `[Moves]`:

```
kGenerator :: Position -> [Moves]
```

Think about what `[Moves]` are; this is likely something like `[[Position]]`, a list of position lists representing the chain of moves.

An obvious way to generate moves from a given position would be doing the 8 possible moves, and then recursively generating more moves from each of these positions.

Hopefully this will help you get through your assignment :)

Comment: thanks 9000. my focus is on the "immutable" knightProblem = kSelector . kFilter . kGenerator chain equation. I only "solved" the problem by introducing compound datatypes so that every component function has only one argument, like kGenerator :: Job -> ..., but that's a different problem and not the specified one :)

Comment: If you need, you can pass an argument "through" a function without changing it. For instance, `kFilter` can accept a tuple `(Position, [Moves])` and return `(Position, [Moves])`, just passing the position to `kSelector` which needs it.